# How to create a category in Xcode 7.2?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, objective-c-category

How do I create a category to an existing Cocoa Touch Class for objective-c in Xcode 7.2? I've been looking for an hour but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. File > New > File…
2. iOS > Source
3. Objective-C File
4. Next
5. File Type: Category

Example:

[image: creating a category file]

Comment: oh, pretty embarrassing, I didn't see Objective-C File at all <.<